# Static Site: Minimal server configuration

Tags: apache, nginx, plesk, nginx-config, static-site

I have a static website generated by Hugo and a web server with Plesk installed.

What is the **minimal server configuration** for a **static website**?

For example: Is it possible to deactivate the PHP support? What else can I deactivate?

My goal is to improve **security** and **performance**. Why not deactivate functions which are not necessary?

Comment: It will be possible, but how to do it will depend on what webserver you are running exactly how to do it, probably best to add that to the question and tags. Also the question is quite broad, as you concerned about anything in particular?

Comment: Well, let's start with the PHP support. Can I deactivate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With nginx if you don't specify to send requests to PHP then it won't use them, so it should not have any impact on security or performance.

```
server {
    server_name  example.org
    root /www/data;

    location / {
    }

    location /images/ {
    }

    location ~ \.(mp3|mp4) {
        root /www/media;
    }
}
```

[Source](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/)

Comment: And what about Apache?

Comment: When I answered the post was tagged Nginx, so I answered for that server. I’ve not used apache for a while but from what I recall you can go through the conf files and comment out anything you are not using and restart.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to focus on the minimum hardware requirements for Plesk - https://docs.plesk.com/release-notes/obsidian/hardware-requirements/

Comment: I already have Plesk installed. I want to know what to deactivate to improve security.